# How to make a low pass filter of current, instead of voltage?

Tags: current, filter, current-source, low-pass

Is there a way to low-pass filter current, rather than voltage?

Let's suppose there is a circuit consisting of a current source and a load.  The current source may have a little bit of current noise at high frequencies.  I'd like to figure out what can be inserted in between the source and load in this case to suppress that.

(Note: the load may not be resistive, and may have strong nonlinearities)

Comment: I don't think passive filters distinguish between current and voltage.

Comment: *Perhaps* an inductor low-pass filter the current.

Comment: A LPF current transfer function is basically taking the Norton Transform of the filter and load . What is the actual load and attenuation of surge currents or I vs f? This can be a simple inductor as long as the load is not inductive already.

Comment: An example: Parallel RC circuit. It acts as a filter if it is driven by a current source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shunt capacitor will filter it.

It will of course lower the high frequency impedance from the infinity of a current source.

So putting a series L after the cap will restore it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flbO8im.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Aside from that, you need to make a low noise current source. LM317's would not be a good place to start.

You are not giving any idea of what noise , voltage or current levels, and how constant-current it needs to be, so hard to make any suggestions, but a simple emitter follower can be very quiet, close to the thermal noise from R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frUnNqm.png)</sup>

In the emitter follower R2 sets the current, ie the current rises until the voltage across R2 is too high, and base current can't flow.

A simple emitter follower has poor current regulation, but good high frequency performance as there is no feedback involved.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh18aH.png)</sup>

Here is an arrangement that gives excellent regulation, low noise at low and high frequencies, and also allows you to switch the LED at very high frequencies, without compromising the noise.

- lots of caps to filter noise, both big electros and small ceramics
- the voltage ref has its noise filtered to give a quiet reference to the opamp.
- the opamp gives an accurate constant current
- we use an emitter follower, as it has intrinsic constant current at high frequencies without the opamp doing anything
- instead of turning it on and off, we steer the current between the test led, and a second matched led. This means that the currents and voltages stay constant during switching. The constant current circuit can have noise filtering, yet still be switched at speed.
- We filter the supply to the leds to reduce the noise input from the power supply.

This is the circuit I used in optical instruments for turbidity, transmission and flourescence.

Comment: This is for something like a LED driver; 1.4-3V at 1-100mA (maybe to 1A in a high-power version).  Could you tell me more about the emitter follower?  Is R2 the load or is it what sets the current level (with the load between collector and V+)?  How do you turn it on/off?  How do you adjust the current?

Comment: So are you just trying to keep RF noise off the wires? (otherwise why would you care about LED brightness noise?)

Comment: Ah, it's for science measurement stuff - brightness noise = measurement error in this case

Comment: So a simple LC or RC filter will work fine. i.e. you can put a big fat electrolytic across the LED if you want

Comment: Yes, in principle, but - it also needs to be possible to turn it on/off at kHz frequencies, so a really big electrolytic is probably a no-no (also I think it could give a brightness decay with a very long tail when turned off if it only discharges through the LED)

Comment: Why don't you describe what you are trying to do? You probably have a photo detector, and its noise is likely to dominate. Why is noise important? Is it really important or is it going to be averaged out?

Answer (score 1):

Filters must have at least one resistive termination. If you drive your circuit with an ideal current source and the load is purely reactive, then you cannot make a filter that works. If your load has some real impedance (e.g. series resistance of a coil) you can design a singly-terminated filter to work with that situation, see for example p. 104 in the [Matthaei Young and Jones book](https://www.microwaves101.com/downloads/MYJ%20part%201.pdf). These will also work if instead your load is reactive, but your source is not ideal, ie has some finite internal resistance.

Answer (score 0):

A *voltage* source has a comparatively low impedance, so a small filter choke in series helps, because it has a higher impedance than the source for AC (or varying DC). In contrast, a *current* source has a high impedance, so if you use a series inductor, it would need to be a large value. A capacitor in parallel would be effective, but that makes the current source behave like a voltage source, because a large peak current could be drawn.

Perhaps you need two stages:

- Filter the current source to remove noise with a capacitor.
- Add a current regulator or limiter in series, after the filter. Depending on regulation, current and voltage needs,

  - this could be a simple series resistor,
  - an IC regulator, e.g. this [LM317 circuit](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf),
    [image: LM317 power IC current regulator]
  - or it might involve multiple components.

Comment: LM317 can output 1.5A  and the adjust-output voltage is 1.25V.  If adjusting from (let's say) 0.1 to 1A, the R1 would have to be a 0.8 to 12.5 ohm potentiometer, rated at 1.87 W.  Is there a source for such components?  The typical potentiometers/trimpots are rated at a lot less power.

Comment: Is that the current range you need? If so, there are wirewound pots that could handle that. But do you need a fixed or variable current limit? See https://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Resistors/Variable-Resistors/Potentiometers/_/N-blay9

Comment: If `The current source may have a little bit of current noise at high frequencies` then using an LM317 will turn that into a truckload of noise.

Comment: ?LM317 is ANALOG, not noisy digital. That said, I've no idea for what purpose this is being used and the schematic was only one possibility.

Comment: Yes. A digital current source has no noise - thats why we like digital. Voltage references are noisy. IC references are worse, because they can't have any useful bypass capacitors to filter the noise. IC regulators are worse again, because they have feedback amplifier poles that boost the noise enormously in part of the spectral range. LM317's are even worse again, because they are now made by random manufacturers in random processes, so you have no idea what you are buying, but it is not what Nat Semi designed 40 years ago, and they can have 60dB higher noise than the original (measured)

Comment: That an amplifier or a resistor has shot noise and thermal noise, certainly -- but "A digital current source has no noise"? Every time an IC switches, capacitors charge and discharge, and high-frequency RF is created. The clock frequency and especially odd harmonics plague input and output, and in a current source, cannot be bypassed lest it no longer be a high-impedance source. See https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9ca1/c9e3ce4e7d6bf4f4041f1e53e4009dd97003.pdf